# Must declare the scalar variable "@jsontest" error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE BASIC_CONFIG_MASTER 
(
BASIC_CONFIG_MASTER_D int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
BASIC_CONFIG_MASTER_N varchar(255) NOT NULL,
BASIC_CONFIG_TYPE char(80) NOT NULL,
BASIC_CONFIG_CHOICES nvarchar(max),
)
```

I want to store a JSON obj in the last column "BASIC_CONFIG_CHOICES"
so I did this after reading a bunch of articles.

```
DECLARE @jsontest NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{"BASIC_CONFIG_MASTER_N":"John Smith","BASIC_CONFIG_TYPE": "string", "BASIC_CONFIG_CHOICES":{"choice1":"123rd West Street, Willow Apt","choice2":"#55 Suite","choice3":12345}}';

INSERT INTO BASIC_CONFIG_MASTER
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@jsontest)
WITH (BASIC_CONFIG_MASTER_N varchar(255),
BASIC_CONFIG_TYPE char(80),
BASIC_CONFIG_CHOICES nvarchar(max) AS JSON
);
```

But then I am getting following error.

```
**Error occurred during SQL query execution

Reason:
SQL Error [137] [S0002]: Must declare the scalar variable "@jsontest".**
```

What is this error and why am I getting this?

Comment: yes , i  ran both the queries as part of one execution

Comment: Wait, are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  You have mixed tags.  SQL Server <> MySQL.  MySQLi is a PHP interface to MySQL.

Comment: sorry, i am using SQL server.

Comment: Sorry, there is something wrong with your SQL.  You don't have the right columns called out in your `INSERT`.  You're trying to insert more columns than you're pulling out of the json.  You should be using `SELECT BASIC_CONFIG_MASTER_N, BASIC_CONFIG_TYPE, BASIC_CONFIG_CHOICES FROM OPENJSON...`  But that won't throw the error you're getting.

Comment: `SQL Error [137] [S0002]:` this sounds like an error from some application that may be sending your two statements separately. Can you please try in Management Studio or Azure Data Studio? (And yes, @squillman is right, your table has four columns, but your JSON only has three. Always use an explicit column list in your `INSERT` and if the first column is an identity don't leave that detail out.)

Comment: I can't replicate your error : [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc313a262c874ac0371b45ed650fdba3)

Comment: Since you had the mysqli tag earlier, are you by chance trying to connect PHP to SQL Server through mysqli?

Comment: no, that was put by mistake, i am using sql server, and i am trying these commands from dbeaver

Comment: Try an officially supported client tool like SSMS or Azure Data Studio, please. And consult the manual or support for your product to see if you've enabled some "feature" that sends each statement as its own batch. Also make sure you aren't highlighting a specific line or using an execution mode that only executes the current statement.

Comment: BASIC_CONFIG_MASTER_D int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
Yet i cannot see it in your JSON string, so it errors on insert as not null field is missing ?

Comment: Yes sure, seems like this can be the issue. Also thanks for suggesting this, will follow this : "Always use an explicit column list in your INSERT". @Aaron Bertrand

Comment: first column is identity, i have updated the post. thanks

Comment: Make sure you do not have a GO in your script, that causes all variables before GO to leave scope.